# Azure service connection error in pipelines and releases

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

After our project's service connection client secret expired, our developers removed and added a new service connection with a new secret.
(It is now obvious that we should have simply updated the client secret in the existing service connection)

After this service connection update, deployments and pipelines for our project start failing.

We considered that this might be caused by a lack of API permissions in the service connection.
When adding new permissions, an Azure authentication error is shown:
"Unsupported token. Unable to initialize authorization context." <--- This error does not really make sense, what could cause it?

[image]

Furthermore, we aren't able to run simple build pipelines because of service connection inconsistencies.
[image]

Can anyone provide advice on what is the proper way to configure this service connection?

We hoped to simply add a new service connection, renew the client secret and have our pipelines resume work.

Comment: Are these classic pipelines or YAML pipelines?

Comment: they are classic pipelines, defined in Azure, I've checked that they use the correct subscription.

Comment: Have you had any luck with this? I'm running into the same issue.

Comment: nothing yet, still stuck